# I was rotating 4 images around a Circle border and showing the related content of the image. But every time I need only content of one image

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I was trying to rotate a circle using animation and show content of specific image by stopping it for some time. But I don't know how to stop it and show the content of specific image.

What I tried!!
**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./rotate.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent-circle">
        <div class="circle blue"></div>
        <div class="circle pink"></div>
        <div class="circle lime"></div>
        <div class="circle orange"></div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 content  pt-2 ">
        <h1>Health Record</h1>
        <p class="w-75">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, doloremque!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body #parent-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 0.4vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite linear;
}
body #parent-circle .circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -14%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.blue {
  background-color: #416ba9;
  transform: translate(10vw);
}
body #parent-circle .circle.pink {
  background-color: #e6427a;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-90deg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: -27%;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.lime {
  background-color: #cddb00;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-180deg);
}
body #parent-circle .circle.orange {
  background-color: #e0592a;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-270deg);
}
.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
}


  @keyframes rotate {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
  }
```

[This Output I was getting but the circle was continuesly rotating I want it it stop at particular place every time and should show its content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePLGU.png).

**What I want**

[This is the Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL1vq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved one of your problems and given you the blueprint to solve the rest of them.

I've updated your keyframes to achieve the flow you're describing.

I hope this gives you a better idea on how to utilize keyframes.

Good luck!

Edit: because of the way you have made your circles (dynamic width/height) make sure to open the snippet in full page.

I would probably make the circles a fixed width and height (like `200px` x `200px`) rather than using `vw`.

```css
body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body #parent-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border: 0.4vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite linear;
}
body #parent-circle .circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: -14%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.blue {
  background-color: #416ba9;
  transform: translate(10vw);
}
body #parent-circle .circle.pink {
  background-color: #e6427a;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-90deg);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: -27%;
}
body #parent-circle .circle.lime {
  background-color: #cddb00;
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-180deg);
}
body #parent-circle .circle.orange {
  background-color: #e0592a;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10vw) rotate(-270deg);
}
.content {
  margin-left: 20%;
}


  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    12.5% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    25% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    37.5% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    62.5% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    75% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    87.5% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./rotate.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent-circle">
        <div class="circle blue"></div>
        <div class="circle pink"></div>
        <div class="circle lime"></div>
        <div class="circle orange"></div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 content  pt-2 ">
        <h1>Health Record</h1>
        <p class="w-75">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, doloremque!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the snippet in full page, since you have used vw to set the width of the circles :)

Comment: Thankyou for the Response. Its Working but I was trying to increase the size of image which is 90 degrees and decrease size of remaining images. How to do that? I have tried using keyframes only but animation of images are going fast.